# Could not authenticate via cookie Error: Unable to refresh user session. Please log in using the magic link flow to enable session persistence

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, magic-sdk

I'm trying to log in with `magic-sdk` and am running into this error:

> Could not authenticate via cookie Error: Unable to refresh user session. Please log in using the magic link flow to enable session persistence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Change your test keys to live keys

Magic no longer accepts test keys. So basically you have to use your live keys even when testing.

Comment: Still not working getting the same error.